# how do i turn off auto-insert of newline after code block?

Tags: c#, resharper

I might have some degree of OCD, maybe that's why it bothers me when I close a line with ';' below a `while{}` `for{}` or other code block and resharper would automatically insert a line break above my line.

I DO NOT want an extra line.

I looked through the Editing option page under braces and new lines, but nothing seems to jump out.

sample:

```
if (true){
   GC.Collect();
}
string s = "Any statement here, ending the line with ';' causes newline above";
```

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Don't use resharper... it's not necessary.

Comment: I assume you've looked at the customization documentation? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/ReSharper+Customization+Guide

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance_Typing_Assistance.html#length_count

Comment: @insane_developer that’s not very helpful. Resharper makes me a much more effective developer. But then I’ve used it for more than a decade.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you mean, can you add a simple code example?

Comment: @stuartd it's a matter of opinion, though.

Comment: @insane_developer but you stated it as a fact, not an opinion

Comment: @stuartd I stated that using resharper is not necessary. Necessary: being essential, indispensable, or requisite. I've also gone more than a decade but without it, and so have many of my peers.

Comment: @insane_developer using any kind of IDE is not ‘necessary’ - all you need is a compiler - but it makes you more productive. Each to their own.

Comment: Personally i find it addictive. Although later version of VS has more overlapping refactoring features built in, Re-sharper still has charms. The more you use it the more familiar you are with the hotkeys. And after a while the code just flies out of your fingers.

Comment: I use VS 2015 @NateW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio (2019) has these formatting settings. I'm assuming you're using VS and resharper isn't doing the formatting.

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > New Line

Find "Place open brace on new line for control blocks". There are a bunch others there as well.

Comment: I'll delete this post if a) OP is not using VS, or b) resharper is doing the formatting.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's Resharper doing the insertion.

Comment: @Haoest - have I misunderstood your question, I thought you didn't like having the additional new line after the closing brace of a control block and the next statement after it. If that is the case then this answer for the VS setting only alters the way the opening brace is formatted.

Answer (score 2):

In ReSharper options: `Code Editing`->`C#`->`Formating Style`->`Blank Lines` - set `After statements with child blocks` to 0.

[image]